# Efficiently writing (and reading) multiple objects to file in Android

Tags: java, android, backup, file-writing, objectoutputstream

I have an Android App and allow my users to back up their data on their phone storage. The data is sensitive and is encrypted first.

Currently I have code similar to the following where I first load an ArrayList of all values to write to file and then perform the actual write.

```
pfd = cResolver.openFileDescriptor(file_uri, "w");
if (pfd != null) {
    ArrayList<Object> toBackup = dbAdapter.getAllDataToBackUp();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(toBackup);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
    pfd.close();
}
```

This works fine for now as the file size is tiny, but the volume of data in the next version will increase significantly, and further versions may also output blob data. The size could easily be 100mb or more in the future.

It doesn't seem an efficient use of memory to encrypt and load every data point and write everything at the same time, and I feel it may be better to do so one item at a time.

Is my concern valid. How would I change the code to write one item at a time? Also, would I need to compress the data myself, or does Java take care of that?

Comment: I think if the operation takes too long, you can switch to another thread also you can explore writing data chunk by chunk i.e. making a buffer of say 4MB and then writing to the file. In general all file operations I do are always on another thread

Comment: Is all data coming from sqlite? Does sqlite contain yet more data?

Comment: `How would I change the code to write one item at a time? ` Dont put the Objects in an array list to begin with as it only takes a lot of memory. Instead adapt dbAdapter.getAllDataToBackUp() which now adds Objects to an array list but should write every Object to file.

Comment: @blackapps that's exactly what I wanted, but wasn't sure which function to use to do that. Would calling writeObject() multiple times overwrite the file, or append the object data?

Comment: I have no idea but i think it will append. But just a little bit of testing will tell you.